# Ansible Playbook : variables

Tags: ansible

I am having an issue with my playbook when I run this playbook as follows

ansible-playbook –i inventory  junos_config_new.yml –check –vvv

```
      name: Juniper SRX configuration compliance checks 
      hosts: juniper
      gather_facts: false
      tasks:
      set_fact:
         config_directory: '{{ "/home/myfolder/ansible_junos/files/" }}'
     - name: Syslog server check
        junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:
           src:'{{ config_directory }}/syslog_config.txt'
           src_format: set
           comment: Ensure that appropriate Syslog server configured 
        register: junos_output
        diff: true
      - debug:
          msg: Syslog server check - This check has failed with the following output({{ junos_output.diff.prepared }})
        when: junos_output.changed 
      - debug:
          msg: Syslog server check - This check has failed with the following output({{ junos_output.diff.prepared }})
         when: junos_output.changed
      - name: Admin credentials check
         junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:
            src: '{{ config_directory }}/admin_user.txt'
            comment: Ensure that Admin user have been created
         diff: true
         register: junos_output1
      - debug:
          var: junos_output1  ***************************************failed section 
      - debug:
          msg: Admin credentials check - This check has passed with the following output({{ junos_output1.diff.prepared }})
        when: not junos_output1.changed 
      - debug:
          msg: Admin credentials check - This check has failed with the following output({{ junos_output1.diff.prepared }})
        when: junos_output1.changed 
      - name: NTP Server check 
          junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:
             src: '{{ config_directory }}/NTP_server.txt'
             comment: Ensure that correct NTP servers has been configured
          diff: true
      - debug:
          var: junos_output2
      - debug:
          msg: NTP Server check  - This check has passed with the following output({{ junos_output2.diff.prepared }})
         when: not junos_output.changed 
      - debug:
          msg: NTP Server check  - This check has failed with the following output({{ junos_output2.diff.prepared }})
        when: junos_output.changed 
 
      - name: Idle timeout check 
          junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:
             src: '{{ config_directory }}/idle_timeout.txt'
             comment: Ensure that idle timeout has been configured
          diff: true
      - debug:
          var: junos_output3
       - debug:
           msg: Idle timeout check   - This check has passed with the following output({{ junos_output3.diff.prepared }})
          when: not junos_output.changed 
       - debug:
           msg: Idle timeout check   - This check has failed with the following output({{ junos_output3.diff.prepared }})
          when: junos_output.changed
```

The error appears to be in '/home/gefelas/ansible_junos/junos_config_new.yml': line 30, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

```
The offending line appears to be:

    register: junos_output1
  - debug:
    ^ here
```

Please let me know what I can change ..

Comment: This is the output of the playbook execution                 https://pastebin.com/QXtFvBdQ

Answer (score 0):

The main cause for the error seems to be that you are using `diff` for the `junos_config` module. According to the documentation, this module does not support `diff`: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/junos_config_module.html

So you'll need to remove the `diff: true` from your `junos_config` tasks.

On another note, you also seem to have multiple issues with indentation, for example this is not the correct indentation:

```
- name: Admin credentials check
   junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:
      src: '{{ config_directory }}/admin_user.txt'
      comment: Ensure that Admin user have been created
   register: junos_output1
```

Make sure you properly indent the task name and additional task parameters like so for all of your tasks:

```
- name: Admin credentials check
  junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:
    src: '{{ config_directory }}/admin_user.txt'
    comment: Ensure that Admin user have been created
  register: junos_output1
```

So I would recommend going over your file and checking the indentation for all tasks (note that this might also be due to StackOverflow formatting).

Comment: I thought the same but if you look at [this](https://junos-ansible-modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/juniper_junos_config.html#examples) `diff` is a valid attribute. They are using it just with `juniper_junos_config:` instead of `junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:` Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: In addition to my comment.

There is the [junos_config](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/junos_config_module.html) module and the [juniper_junos_config](https://junos-ansible-modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/juniper_junos_config.html) module.

The first one doesn't has the attribute `diff`. The second one has it.

Comment: The error `The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'diff'` indicates that this field is not returned from the module, so that might be worth investigating.